# Identifying where does the page navigate to (using JavaScript only)

Tags: javascript

Assuming a user is at `A.html` and his target is `B.html`.
I want to be able to know he got from A to B, assuming I have control only on the client side.

As I see it, there are 2 main cases (ignoring IFrames etc.):
 1. Navigating through `hrefs` (which are relatively easy to handle using event handlers (like `onClick()`).
 2. Redirection from another page - which is a problem because of the involvement of the server side.

Comment: Have you thought about putting a param on the URL like "referrer=<origin>" and using window.location.href when loading the page to check the origin of the request? It's kind of the same logic of a "landing page".

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use `document.referrer` and `document.location` to implement logic which decides the path your user has followed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it on the server side if its for analytics (keep a log of which pages the user has visited, in order).

Or use cookies to track the same thing on the client side. On entering each page append the page name / ID / url to a cookie (some sort of ID would be better if your URLs are too long)